# Prove that $ |X| \leq |Y| $ if $d(x) \geq d(y) \forall x,y \in E $ in a bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Prove that $ |X| \leq |Y| $ if $d(x) \geq d(y) \forall x,y \in E $ in a bipartite graph with equality valid if and only if $d(x) = d(y) \forall x,y \in E $ where d(v) stands for degree of vertex v

Why does it say $x,y \in E $ ? Aren't they vertices?

My approach:-

$$ |X| \leq d(y) \forall y$$
$$ |Y| \leq d(x) \forall x$$ 
And we have $$d(x) \geq d(y) \forall x,y $$ any help?

Comment: What do you mean with $d$? And are $X,Y$ finite sets?

Comment: d(v) stands for degree of vertex v. In this case, X and Y are two sets of vertices; each edge of a bipartite graph has one end in X and the other end in Y - definition of a bipartite graph.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought $d$ was some kind of distance function.

Comment: What textbook is this? It might just be that the $E$ is just a typo - I'd see if the publisher/author has released any errata.

Comment: Perhaps "$x,y \in E$ is not supposed to mean $x \in E$ and $y \in E$" but rather "the ordered pair $(x,y)$ is in $E$".

Answer (score 5):

Since the question as stated doesn't make sense, I'm guessing that the real question is the following:

> Consider a bipartite graph with partite sets $X,Y$ and edge set $E,$ and with no isolated vertices. Prove that, if $\operatorname{d}(x)\ge\operatorname{d}(y)$ whenever $x\in X,\ y\in Y,\ xy\in E$$,$ then $|X|\le|Y|,$ with equality only if $\operatorname{d}(x)=\operatorname{d}(y)$ for each edge $xy\in E.$

**Proof:**
$$|X|=\sum_{xy\in E}\frac1{\operatorname{d}(x)}\le\sum_{xy\in E}\frac1{\operatorname{d}(y)}=|Y|$$
**Explanation of the equalities:** Recall that there are no isolated vertices. For each vertex $x\in X$ let $E_x$ be the set of all edges incident with $x.$ Then
$$\sum_{xy\in E}\frac1{\operatorname d(x)}=\sum_{x\in X}\sum_{xy\in E_x}\frac1{\operatorname d(x)}=\sum_{x\in X}\left(\frac1{\operatorname d(x)}\cdot\sum_{xy\in E_x}1\right)=\sum_{x\in X}\left(\frac1{\operatorname d(x)}\cdot|E_x|\right)=\sum_{x\in X}1=|X|.$$

Comment: Oh, now I see where I misunderstood OP.

Comment: I'm not quite thorough with $|X|=\sum_{xy\in E}\frac1{\operatorname{d}(x)}$ or $  \sum_{xy\in E}\frac1{\operatorname{d}(y)}=|Y|$

Comment: I edited an explanation of $|X|=\sum_{xy\in E}\frac1{\text d(x)}$ into my answer. But what do you think of my interpretation of the question?

Comment: Such a nice and explicit explanation!

Comment: The [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353578/continuous-bijective-function-between-the-same-topology-that-is-not-a-homeomorph/1354504#1354504) on bijective, continuous non-homeomorphisms has been re-opened if you’d like to post the answer that you deleted from the non-duplicate.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott OK, thanks.